# onStop() not getting called when I press the back button

Tags: android

Is this normal.

The docs say

"The onStart() and onStop() methods can be called multiple times, as the activity alternates between being visible and hidden to the user"

When I press the back button an it will go back to the previous activity which totally covers the old one.

What is going on here?

Comment: Can you show us a snippet of relevant code you are using to track the onStop method?

Answer (score -7, accepted):

You want onPause(), not onStop(). onStop is called just before the activity is destoryed, when the system is low on memory. onPause is called whenever the user navigates away from your activity. See diagram at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle.

Comment: Thanks, in the diagram it says "Activity is no longer visible" and then onStop() occurs, so what does "no longer visible" mean then?  I would have thought that going to an activity means no longer visible.

Comment: In my understanding, android makes a distinction between "another activity in the foreground" (onPause is called, but your activity continues to have a VM and operate), and "activity is no longer visible because it is about to be killed" (onStop, and later, onDestroy is called). So onPause will be called every time your activity is hidden, immediately, whereas onStop is called less often. This is just my take on things, and is probably somewhat inaccurate, but the android docs say "The foreground lifetime of an activity happens between a call to onResume until a corresponding call to onPause."

Comment: What I can do if my Activity is for SINGLE USE only How do I exit and leave VM every time onPause is called...  see my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928591/a-strange-behavior-of-android-activities-fragments-and-intent

Comment: This is not correct. onStop is called whenever the activity is not visible, for example if a child activity has been launched on top of it. The callback when an activity is about to be destroyed is onDestroy,

Answer (score 8):

`onStop()` is called each time Activity is no longer visible.
So when back button is pressed `onStop()` is actually called.

Easy check, - need to put break points in `onStop()/onStart()` callbacks and run debugging session.

BUT note that `onStop()` of current Activity will most probably be called AFTER `onStart()/onResume()` of Activity to which you are switching.

Hence, I think you were trying to update something in `onStop()` of 1st Activity and were expecting to fetch updated data in `onStart()` of 2nd Activity which caused errors.

Comment: It is not very common to people talk about lifecycle related to others activity lifecycle. I have never heard that onStop could be called after onStart of other.

Comment: @RodrigoBorba I think it implies from `onPause()` reference doc:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause(). Specifically: `When activity B is launched in front of activity A, this callback will be invoked on A. B will not be created until A's onPause() returns, so be sure to not do anything lengthy here.`

Answer (score 0):

If you still need those to get called for your activity instance when a new instance is created, you can use [this *hacky* solution](https://gist.github.com/milosmns/0df33f49be9e44698af9).
Just implement your logic in #doStopOperation() and #doDestroyOperation() instead of #onStop() and #onDestroy() - and be sure to call super#onStop() and super#onDestroy() from your overridden methods. Obviously when extending this activity, you don't need to extend the AppCompatActivity, you can use the regular activity instead. This works for me in a production build, so hopefully it will help.

I guess you could write a timer hack as well to invoke *stop* and *destroy* even when no new instance is created, but that's up to you.