# onRestart method is not called after returning

Tags: android, android-activity

My `MainActivity` has a `Button` that when it is pressed this method is called:

```
 public void sendMessage(View view) {
    //Do something in response to the button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

So the app displays `DisplayMessageActivity`, then ActionBar is pressed to return to the `MainActivity`. And I have a `onRestart` which I think should be called when returning to the `MainActivity` (it does return to `MainActivity`), but it is not called. What seems to be the problem?

`onRestart` method:

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(str);
    setContentView(textView);
}
```

Comment: Feel free to accept an answer if it fits your needs :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the `onResume()` method.  `onRestart()` is called after stopping your `Activity` not just pausing it.  Check out the [`Activity` Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) diagram for more information.

Comment: Android reference says: _once the activity is fully-obstructed and not visible, it stops._. So when returning it should call `onRestart`, shouldn't it?

Comment: It's not really clear to anyone.  Even Roman Guy said he struggles with it.  But You can count on `onResume()` and `onPause()` being called.

Comment: @Sam me too agree with what you are saying and also tried the sample application given on android developer's site and it is also behaving the same.

Answer (score 1):

According to [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325767/onstop-not-getting-called-when-i-press-the-back-button) post you want onResume. Here is some more input:

1. [onPause() & onResume()](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html)
2. [The lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png)
3. [**Stopping and Restarting an Activity**](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html)

Edit:

But as I read here:

> The user performs an action in your app that starts a new activity. The current activity is stopped when the second activity is created. If the user then presses the Back button, the first activity is restarted. 
>   Source: [Stopping and Restarting an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html)

you are right...

Comment: Thanks, android seems inconsistent